ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova -- but I'm not using Cordova
I've written and launched a PWA recently -- 100% HTML/CSS/JS/Jquery. Plus mobiscroll (a really old open source version), underscore, and cropper (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper).
I've gone through every single JS file in my code and all the included libraries. There are zero references to any variable or object "cordova" anywhere.
I have some code to catch browser errors/crashes and upload the stacktrace to my server and send me an alert me when this happens.  I have about 5000 people a day using the new PWA, but 2 or 3 times a day, I'll get this crash report: **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova **
It's driving me nuts trying to find what or where this error is being generated.
I will add that this app used to be a Cordova app in the App stores, but I stripped out all references to plugins, cordova objects or variables, or any code that was Cordova based. There's no more config.xml, no more cordova.js. None of the JS libraries I'm using nor the HTML or CSS have any references to "cordova".
I've done the following on my entire file structure and it returns nothing.
grep cordova * -R

I've tried grep'ing all the files in my source tree both locally and on the web server.
I've searched all the JS libraries and all other files for a reference.
The stacktrace does not return a usable line:column or even a source file for the error. It just says "global code@"
The common answer of "Include  in your index.html file" does not apply, as I'm not actually using Cordova.
Any ideas where or how the browser is finding a reference to cordova that's not defined?
Thank you.
